# CentOS mail server

Tags: centos, email-server

What do I install so that I can receive and send email on a CentOS server? I will need to be able to have multiple domains and users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos#head-0facb50d5796bee0bd394636c32ffa9a997a6ab5

or

http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-centos-6.2-x86_64

maybe?

Comment: Thank you :) Now if i know what i need i can look for more tutorials.